# Whats the idea behind task clean on gradle android projects

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I create a new project on android studio I see in `gradle.build`:

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Whats the idea behind it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this way the `clean` task (with the type=delete) deletes the build directory when it runs.

It is useful when you modify some config files like the `settings.gradle` which can requires a complete clean.

Comment: Im having some issues with submodules when adding classes or changing packages, maybe adding this manually may fix that?

Comment: @danielgomezrico It depends by the issues

Comment: Does Build -> Clean project in Android Studio call this manually? I’m considering to remove it from my project’s gradle file since I feel it adds to the project Run time.

Comment: I'm a bit sad this isn't the default behavior by gradle... I can't imagine why someone would run the 'clean' task but not want to clean _everything_.